# Javascript Classes - Accessing a function on the fly

Tags: javascript, class

I have a javascript class:

```
MyClass = function(){
    this.m_SomeData = 5;
};
```

and I have created some functions for that class:

```
MyClass.prototype.MyClassFunction_1 = function(arg){
    // Some stuff that can return false
    return true;
};
MyClass.prototype.MyClassFunction_2 = function(arg){
    // Some stuff that can return false
    return true;
};
MyClass.prototype.MyClassFunction_3 = function(arg){
    // Some stuff that can return false
    return true;
};
```

Later on I have created an instance of that class. (They could be combined into a single function but there are design issues that make it nicer to separate them):

```
var myInstance = new MyClass();
```

Now the tricky bit. In an 'if' statement I am doing the following (as well as other stuff).

```
var funcUse;
var arg = 3; // Some value created at run time)
if((funcUse = val === 0 ? MyClassFunction_1
                        : (val === 1 ? MyClassFunction_2 : MyClassFunction_3)) !== "undefined" &&
    myInstance.funcUse(arg)){
}
```

The obvious problem is in the 'if' statement MyClassFunction_? are all undefined as they should be tied to an instance of the class, eg myInstance.MyClassFunction_?.

So how can this be done nicely in an if statement?

Comment: Methods are just properties with function values. You can use bracket notations for them as well.

Comment: That's not a class, that's a function.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, can you explain what you mean? (@melpomene - that is one way you create classes in javascipt.)

Comment: @Rewind: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Comment: No, a constructor is not a class.

Comment: @melpomene: constructor + prototype form a class (even when the prototype is empty)

Comment: @melpomene, A class is just a template definition of an object's properties and methods. It's incorrect place to holywars here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var funcUse =
    val === 0 ? 'MyClassFunction_1' :
    val === 1 ? 'MyClassFunction_2' :
    'MyClassFunction_3';

if (myInstance[funcUse] && myInstance[funcUse](arg)) {
    ...
}
```

Dot notation (`obj.property`) is just syntactic sugar for `obj["property"]`, so you can simply make `funcUse` a string.

---

Alternatively, you can also do this:

```
var funcUse =
    val === 0 ? myInstance.MyClassFunction_1 :
    val === 1 ? myInstance.MyClassFunction_2 :
    myInstance.MyClassFunction_3;

if (funcUse && funcUse.call(myInstance, arg)) {
    ...
}
```

This extracts the function from the `myInstance` object, but then you have to be careful with calling `funcUse` to make sure `myInstance` is passed as `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about *"classes"*/inheritance, the problem you want to solve is really two more simple ones,

1. Accessing a property of an *Object* dynamically
2. Choosing the context/`this` of a *function*

You have a couple choices about which pattern to use

---

`fn.call` / `fn.apply`

```
var o = {foo: 'bar'};

function fizz() {return this;}

fizz.call(o); // returns `o`, Object {foo: 'bar'}
```

---

Bracket notation

```
var o = {foo: function () {return this}};

o['foo'](); // returns `o`
```

---

In your particular case I'd probably go with a `switch..case` or `if..else` pattern to decide on the property name, then invoke with bracket notation;

```
var method;
switch (val) {
    case 0: method = 'foo'; break;
    case 1: method = 'bar'; break;
}

if (method)
    o[method]();
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative input. I marked melpomene's answer with the tick as it appeared first. But thanks again.